# Any way to call an object as a function?

Tags: javascript, function, object

I want to be able to do something like

```
var x = {};
x.something = function(y){
   console.log(y);
};
x("hi"); // Call it without using .something
```

Is this possible? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var x = function(str) {
  return x.something(str);
};

x.something = function(str) { 
  console.log(str);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions are objects, so you could do something like:

```
var x = function(y) {
  console.log(y);
}
x.prop = function(){ return 'This works'; };

x('hi');
console.log(x.prop());
```